# Use seekbar on Wear OS without dismissing the frame

Tags: android, kotlin, android-view, wear-os

## The problem

I am developing an IoT application for Wear OS, and I would like to set the brightness of a light with a seekbar. However, moving the seekbar from left to right causes the Fragment to dismiss, which is bad for the user experience. I have tried using [SwipeDismissFrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/wear/widget/SwipeDismissFrameLayout) to avoid this, but it is not working. Any advice? I would like to reproduce the behavior of the Google Home app. I must use Android View, I cannot use compose.

### Fragment Layout

This is the fragment that contains the RecyclerView with the list of devices

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.wear.widget.SwipeDismissFrameLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dismiss_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <androidx.wear.widget.WearableRecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/light_list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:itemCount="10"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_device" />
</androidx.wear.widget.SwipeDismissFrameLayout>
```

### Item Layout

This is the layout I use to display an item:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/light_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginVertical="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <SeekBar
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:id="@+id/brightness_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="@dimen/device_item_height"
        android:minHeight="@dimen/device_item_height"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_drawable"
        android:splitTrack="false"
        android:thumbTint="@android:color/transparent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/light_checkbox" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/light_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:button="@drawable/ic_lights"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

## What I tried

I tried to reduce the sensitivity of the swipe-to-dismiss gesture with `setDismissMinDragWidthRatio(0)`, but nothing changed. I also tried setting `setSwipable(false)`, but again, nothing changed. Finally, I tried inserting a random HorizontalView inside the ConstraintLayout, and scrolling the horizontal view content from left to right did not trigger the swipe-to-dismiss gesture.

Answer (score 0):

Create a theme in values/themes.xml, something like this

```
 <style name="DisableSwipeBack" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
      <item name="android:windowSwipeToDismiss">false</item>
 </style>
```

or you can add the **windowSwipeToDismiss** to your current theme...

Then set it to your activity tag, this way

```
android:theme="@style/DisableSwipeBack"
```

Done, that activity wont have swipe back anymore... I recommend to add a close/back button if you disable the swipe back as users can set the watch back button to another functionality

Oh and there is no need for the **SwipeDismissFrameLayout** tag, you can remove that too

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I would like to avoid this solution if possible, because I don't have enough space to add a back button